# js Coverflow that works in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, coverflow

I am trying to add a converflow effect to my site and I have found this one:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/coverflow/demo/demo.html

This works great in FF but fails in IE (7, 8)

I have found others but they either work in IE or FF not in both.

Does anyone know of a jquery coverflow script that works in FF and IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cloud Carousel](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm)

Works in IE 7 to 9, Firefox and Opera (tested by me)... Author says it supports Chrome and Safari too

In IE 7 and 8, it uses a different rendering... For the others, use canvas

Comment: That effect is not like the coverflow effect. That's why it's called Carousel and not Coverflow

Comment: Ok, this is the one I use, even if having to style it a little bit... But there are many cross-browser jquery carousel plugins out there, good luck

Comment: But I really need coverflow :( Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't see where the problem lies... You can reproduce that coverflow effect with a carousel plugin with little tweaking... Making the selected item bigger, and so on

Comment: Not really. If you notice in the effect the images are not only behind but also in an 45º angle

Comment: Well after much consideration I will accept this as the correct answer since I really can't find a better jquery plugin :) Thanks Andre

Comment: Now that you said, I opened with IE9... I had opened with Opera, so it fails to a simple carousel... sorry for not realizing that... You can just apply a transform, it will not work with older browsers, but degrades nicely

Answer (score 0):

http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php
is an interesting one, but they all suck actually because the perspective effect sint there.

http://www.canvasdemos.com/2010/12/27/coulisse/ is better but completely different programmed.